Unable to disable sconfig at startup using ansible
I am creating the module to disable sconfig at startup for allusers on servercore version. I am running the below code:
#!powershell

# Copyright: (c) 2024, MyName

#AnsibleRequires -CSharpUtil Ansible.Basic

$spec = @{
   options = @{}
     supports_check_mode = $true
}

$module = [Ansible.Basic.AnsibleModule]::Create($args, $spec)

$checkMode = $module.CheckMode

try {
#Get the information if server is 'server core' version
$servercore = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\').InstallationType -eq 'Server Core'
    if ($servercore) {
        # Check sconfig autolaunch status
        $sconfig = Get-SConfig -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $sconfig = $sconfig.AutoLaunch
        
        if ($sconfig) {
            # If sconfig autolaunch status is set to true then change the status to false
            Set-SConfig -AutoLaunch $false -AllUsers -WhatIf:$checkMode
            $module.Result.message = "SConfig AutoLaunch has been set to false."
            $module.Result.changed = $true
        }
        else {
            $module.Result.message = "SConfig AutoLaunch has already been set to false."
        }
    }
   else {
        $module.Result.message = "Server is not server core version"      
    }
}
catch {
  # Handle the errors while fetching server core version informationn
  $module.FailJson("An error occurred while fetching the sconfig information: $_")
}

$module.ExitJson()

Now, let me explain the problem. If I go to directly on the server, it works perfectly fine. However when I run via ansible playbook. I get the below error:
"msg": "An error occurred while fetching the sconfig information: Cannot bind argument to 
parameter 'Path' because it is null.[0].Exception.Message"

It seems that problem is lying with:
(Get-SConfig).AutoLaunch

This command gives output without any error. Since ansible uses winrm so I thought to use below command locally on server:
Invoke-Command {Get-SConfig} -ComputerName $env:ComputerName

It gives the same error 'cannot bind the parameter' but also gives output. If I use -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue', it suppresses the error so I only get the output.
In the error it refers to the 'path' that is at line number 176 of sconfig.psm1 file located under C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.ServeCore.SConfig\2.0.0.0. I am attaching the screenshot as well. In the above powershell script, even if I use ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'. It doesn't work. Not sure what is happening. I have tried this command in server Desktop exp. version by removing 'server core' check, it has same issue there also.
One more important aspect. If I remove try catch block in above script on either of the server version 'servercore or desktop exp', it works perfectly fine. I am using it on my office system but I have tested it on my personal lab with server core version, it has same result. I downloaded the servercore module but same issue. Please help me to resolve this issue. Let me know if anyone needs any further information.
Thanks
Jatinder Pal Singh (JPS)

Any help would be appreciated.
